# problems to copy data from rest api Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from Office 365 Management API using Copy activity in ADF and REST API dataset.
I am stuck on step when I see that data is fetched from copy activity but with error related to Source and of course I could not save data to some sink.

Error is :
{
"errorCode": "2200",
"message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorMoreThanOneObjectsReturned,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=More than one objects returned\r\n{\r\n  "CreationTime": "2020-07-15T11:59:57",\r\n  ....  and some data.

Of course I am expected some json data in response but error 'More than one objects returned' confused me.

//Alexander